# Committing to GITHUB using specific username from command line

Tags: git, github

I am new to GITHUB and I am using command line to work on it. When every I made a commit it is committing with generic username(xyz), how can I commit the changes with my username from command line.

In SVN we pass command --username --password, do we have any thing similar to that in GITHUB ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up your gitconfig as described in the Your Identity section.
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

If you want to set the author explicitly, see using the author flag when you commit.
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: I am trying to set explicitly but I am getting below error ?       fatal: No existing author found with

Comment: @ramchander are you doing git commit -author <author@example.com>?

Comment: No. I am doing git commit --author=<author>